# i want to download all images in zip file by click on download button in ci

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i want to download image files in zip format by click on download button.

view

```
<table class="table" id="ItrDetailTable">

    <thead class="ItrDetailThead">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Sr.No.</th>
        <th scope="col">Pan No.</th>
        <th scope="col">Mobile</th>
        <th scope="col">Assestment Year</th>
        <th scope="col">Residential Status</th>
        <th scope="col">Employee Category</th>
        <th scope="col">Payment Status</th>
        <th scope="col">ITR Status</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable">
    <?php if (count($records)):
        $count = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $key = +$count;
        ?>
        <?php $n = 1;
        foreach (@$records as $record): ?>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><?php echo $key++ + 1; ?></th>
                <td class="ItrDetailTd"> <?php echo $record->panno; ?></td>
                <td class="ItrDetailTd"><?php echo $record->mobno; ?></td>
                <td class="ItrDetailTd"><?php echo $record->assessment_year; ?>  </td>
                <td class="ItrDetailTd">  <?php echo $record->residential_status; ?></td>
                <td class="ItrDetailTd">  <?php echo $record->employee_category; ?>   </td>
                <td class="ItrDetailTd">  <?php echo $record->Payment_Status; ?>   </td>
                <td class="ItrDetailTd">  <?php echo $record->itr_status; ?> </td>
                <td class="ItrDetailTd">
                <a title="View" href="<?php echo base_url('admin/orders_history?itr_id=' . $record->id) ?>"
                       class="btn btn-primary">View Orders  </a>

                <a href="<?php  echo base_url("Admin/DownloadITRDetails/{$record->id}"); ?>">&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button></a>                </td>

            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

controller

```
    public function DownloadITRDetails($record_id)
    {
        $this->load->library('zip');
        $this->load->helper('file');
        $path = "./services/v3/uploads/FORM16/";
        $files = get_filenames($path);
//        print_r($files);die;
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $this->zip->read_file($path . $file, true);
        }
        $this->zip->download("download files");
    }
```

[This is my page image.i want to download all images by their ids.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/higpd.jpg)

Comment: what is the issue? please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve when writing questions and follow proper formatting

Comment: sir when i click download button thats give me full folder image

Comment: what does that mean?